# Zlib Inflate buffer error

Tags: ruby

```
def deflate(string, level)
  z = Zlib::Deflate.new(level)
  dst = z.deflate(string, Zlib::NO_FLUSH)
  z.close
  return dst
end

def inflate(string)
  zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new
  buf = zstream.inflate(string)
  zstream.finish
  zstream.close
  return buf
end

a = deflate("asasasas",6)
p a
p inflate(a)
```

Gives me a buffer error on line

```
  zstream.finish
```

Why is that? Ruby 1.8.7 I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on deflate says:

> Normally the parameter flush is set to Z_NO_FLUSH, which allows
>   deflate to decide how much data to accumulate before producing output,
>   in order to maximize compression.

By using Zlib::NO_FLUSH the returned value is not the entire deflated stream. Use **Zlib::FINISH** instead.

The functions you've written are the ones provided in the Zlib::Deflate / Zlib::Inflate documentation. You could replace all the code you've written with:

```
a = Zlib::Deflate.deflate("asasasas", 6)
p a
p Zlib::Inflate.inflate(a)
```

Comment: If I use Zlib::Inflate.inflate(a) it throws the buffer error. That's why I decided to write those methods. Now, when I use Zlib::FINISH instead of zstream.finish just returns me an empty string.

Comment: I've tested it against 1.9.2. Maybe it behaves differently on different ruby versions? Are you using 1.8.7 as you said originally?

Comment: Just tested it on 1.8.7 and it works (used **ruby -rzlib -e 'p Zlib::Inflate.inflate(Zlib::Deflate.deflate("asasasas", 6))'** ) Try that and see what happens.